# Python BLE Bleak Device not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm trying to use the Adafruit_CircuitPython_BLE_iBBQ python library (see https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_BLE_iBBQ) to connect to the INKBIRD Smart Wireless BBQ Thermometer. I have used conda and the circuitpython docs to successfully create a circuit python environment. I'm running the sample code at https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/ble_ibbq/en/latest/examples.html.

It correctly finds the iBBQ advertisement but then throws
`bleak.exc.BleakError: Device with address FC:45:C3:38:76:03 was not found.`
Does anyone know how this might be addressed?

Thank you!

Comment: You can test it is not the BBQ device by using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool (like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)) to connect and read data. If that works, then on your Raspberry Pi, open a terminal and start the `bluetoothctl` tool. When the test script runs it should report the devices found during scan and when it is connecting. There might be more debug information in that log. Try connecting from `bluetoothctl` with `connect FC:45:C3:38:76:03` (if that is the correct address for the BBQ device.